# Updating a specific column in sql table with information of a data frame in r

Tags: sql, r, odbc, rodbc

I have a sql connection, and i get information to work with algorithms in r. So in FTSE100 i get the result of my algorithm in a data frame in R like this.

```
canlSQL<-odbcConnect("Myconnection")
```

`DATE         AMSTEOE FTSE100 FRCAC40 DAXINDX 
1 03/01/1994  190.76    2  2290.56  2267.98 
2 04/01/1994  190.99    3  2274.34  2253.58 
3 05/01/1994  191.68    4  2249.55  2233.41 
4 06/01/1994  192.21    6  2275.06  2220.22 
5 07/01/1994  192.41    3  2307.55  2211.64 
6 10/01/1994  192.59    2  2317.25  2233.79 
.
.
.
.
1000 10/01/1999  200.59    5  2317.25  2233.79`

In SQL i have a table with the same structure but more columns, I want update the FTSE_A column in SQL with the information of FTSE100 column of the data frame in R.

`DATE.REF     AMST_A FTSE_A  FRCA_A   DAX_A COL.1 COL.2 COL.3
1 03/01/1994  190.76    NA  2290.56  2267.98   NA    NA   NA
2 04/01/1994  190.99    NA  2274.34  2253.58   NA    NA   NA 
3 05/01/1994  191.68    NA  2249.55  2233.41   NA    NA   NA 
4 06/01/1994  192.21    NA  2275.06  2220.22   NA    NA   NA 
5 07/01/1994  192.41    NA  2307.55  2211.64   NA    NA   NA 
6 10/01/1994  192.59    NA  2317.25  2233.79   NA    NA   NA 
.
.
.
.
1000 10/01/1999  200.59  NA  2317.25  2233.79  NA    NA   NA`

So i would like to have the next result:

`DATE.REF     AMST_A FTSE_A  FRCA_A   DAX_A COL.1 COL.2 COL.3
1 03/01/1994  190.76    2   2290.56  2267.98   NA    NA   NA
2 04/01/1994  190.99    3   2274.34  2253.58   NA    NA   NA 
3 05/01/1994  191.68    4   2249.55  2233.41   NA    NA   NA 
4 06/01/1994  192.21    6   2275.06  2220.22   NA    NA   NA 
5 07/01/1994  192.41    3   2307.55  2211.64   NA    NA   NA 
6 10/01/1994  192.59    2   2317.25  2233.79   NA    NA   NA 
.
.
.
.
1000 10/01/1999  200.59  5  2317.25  2233.79  NA    NA   NA`

I have tried to do the next in R:

```
for(i in 1:1000){
sqlQuery(canlSQL,paste0("UPDATE MYTABLE SET FTSE_A= '",DATAFRAME$FTSE100[i],"'"))
}
```

I don't get an error when i run the code, but in the SQL results i get the next:

`DATE.REF     AMST_A FTSE_A  FRCA_A   DAX_A COL.1 COL.2 COL.3
1 03/01/1994  190.76    5   2290.56  2267.98   NA    NA   NA
2 04/01/1994  190.99    5   2274.34  2253.58   NA    NA   NA 
3 05/01/1994  191.68    5   2249.55  2233.41   NA    NA   NA 
4 06/01/1994  192.21    5   2275.06  2220.22   NA    NA   NA 
5 07/01/1994  192.41    5   2307.55  2211.64   NA    NA   NA 
6 10/01/1994  192.59    5   2317.25  2233.79   NA    NA   NA 
.
.
.
.
1000 10/01/1999  200.59  5  2317.25  2233.79  NA    NA   NA`

I don't need the where condition, because if I use the WHERE condition i could get a duplicated FTSE_A result, the columns don't have a unique value to pass the unique result of FTSE100. Actually when i use the WHERE condition I get values in wrong places.

I need to update the FTSE_A column in the SQL table, some one know how i can update it with the results obtained in R, but just the FTSE_A column?

Comment: Your (**_CONDITIONLESS_**) update command updates the column `FTSE_A` setting the same value for all rows in the table. You MUST have a `WHERE` clause to tell the DB which records should be updated.

Comment: One unique indicator I see is the *DATE.REF* field, specifying distinct month starts per year. Can you not condition on that?

Comment: Actually the DATE.REF field could have repeated dates, because in the data frame the columns have different values in the same day. I just need put the results in the column that i want, but i don't know if i have to use the UPDATE or if there is other function to update or insert the values that i want in the SQL table.